# insert NA for duplicated values in a column using R

Tags: r

I got data like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), time = c(412, 
412, 412, 121, 121, 121, 250, 250)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

and I want the duplicated values in the time column, replaced with NAS

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), time2 = c(412, 
NA, NA, 121, NA, NA, 250, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `duplicated` -

```
df$time[duplicated(df$time)] <- NA
df

#  id time
#1  1  412
#2  1   NA
#3  1   NA
#4  2  121
#5  2   NA
#6  2   NA
#7  3  250
#8  3   NA
```

---

A `dplyr` option would be to assign `NA` for all the `time` values except the 1st one for each `id`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(time = replace(time, -1, NA)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

With base function `is.na<-`, it's as simple as

```
is.na(df$time) <- duplicated(df$time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[duplicated(time), time := NA]
```

-output

```
> df1
   id time
1:  1  412
2:  1   NA
3:  1   NA
4:  2  121
5:  2   NA
6:  2   NA
7:  3  250
8:  3   NA
```